# jQuery move item in an array to index 0 on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have this setup an array and then stored each img on the page with an output on doc load:

```
// Create array to store file path
var sliderImg = []; 
// Locate each img on page
$('.thumbnail').children().each(function() {
// Take src and store it in array wrapped in img HTML
sliderImg.push('<img class="stacked" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" src="' +            $(this).attr('src') + '" />');
});
```

There are multiple imgs on this page so if one is clicked how can I move it to the front (index 0 of the array)?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the array?

Comment: `.splice()` it out of the array, then `.unshift()` it so it's at the front?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
    var sliderImgIndexes = [];
    var index_lookup_sliderImg = {};

    $('.thumbnail').children().each(function( index ) {
      $(this).data("src_index", index); 
      $(this).click(update_index);
      var order_index = sliderImgIndexes.push(index);
      index_lookup_sliderImg['src_index_' + index] = '<img class="stacked" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />';
    });

    function update_index(){
      var src_index = $(this).data("src_index");
      var indexin = $.inArray(src_index, sliderImgIndexes);
      sliderImgIndexes.splice(indexin, 1); //removes 1 element from indexin
      sliderImgIndexes.unshift(src_index);
    }

    function get_sliderImgArray(){
        var returnImgs = [];
        $.each(sliderImgIndexes, function(i,srcindex){
          returnImgs.push(index_lookup_sliderImg['src_index_' + srcindex]);
        });
        return returnImgs;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/30p2xnkh/1/

Comment: But the OP's items are all already in the array and he or she wants to reorder them.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to first remove the image from the array using array.splice(index,howmanyitems), Then use array.unshift(item) to push the item into the first spot of the array.

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click','img.stacked',function(){
    var item = $(this);
    var n = sliderImg.indexOf(item);
    if (n!=-1){
        sliderImg.splice(n,1);
        sliderImg.unshift(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing an array of HTML strings.. So it will be difficult to identify the item's index in the array.

Since you're probably rendering them,  you can push the rendered element to the array. 
Then assuming the element you clicked on is $el, you can do:

```
var imageIndex= sliderImg.indexOf($el);
sliderImg.splice(imageIndex,1);
sliderImage.unshift($el);
```

Note: this will not reorder them in the DOM! To do that, its simpler:

```
var el = $(this);
var children =el.parent().children();
el.parent().append(children.not(el));
```

Or one of many other possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, check for a condition, and move item to beginning of the array:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
    {
      var move_this_item = false;

      if (results[i].param_to_check == value_to_move) move_this_item = true;  

      if (move_this_item == true)
      {
          var item_holder = results[i];
          results.splice(i,1);
          results.unshift(item_holder);

          break;
      }
    }
```